# How to include jars from libs folder to another jar?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have Gradle JAR (Main) project. I have other commons-io jars (dependent) that I would like to package them with the Main JAR. I tried below, but when I decompile Main JAR, I see all the dependent JARS inside libs folder with .jar extension.

```
jar {
    from("$projectDir") {
        include 'libs/**'
    }
}
```

What I want is the class files from all the dependent JARs into Main JAR. I am doing this because the Main JAR is going to be used by multiple projects. So that way, I do not have to include all the dependent JARs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know You cannot pack other jars into single jar just like that. What You need to do is to extract all the jars and pack the content into single file.

Following piece of code prepares such jar for declared dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: jar) {
  baseName = project.name + '-fat'
  deps = configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  from(deps) { 
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I have done. As I mentioned the re-packaged JAR contains all the dependent JAR in a folder 'lib'. I don't want that because I want user of my JAR to able to use classes from dependent JARs.

Comment: Hm.. As far as I see the `fat.jar` artifact prepared with this script doesn't even have a `lib` folder. It contains all repackaged dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

use this.

```
into(libForderName){
        from {
            configurations.compile.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : it.getAbsoluteFile()
            }
        }
    }
```